# Use custom bitmap instead of character glyph in font

Tags: java, fonts, swt, styledtext

I have a StyledText and I'm trying to use a custom bitmap for a tab character instead of the character glyph used in the font. Is there any way to replace one of the glyphs? If not, then is there a listener that is called when each character is drawn?

Comment: Verify that no existing [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) glyph meets your requirements.

Comment: Even if a unicode glyph does, I wont be able to use it as I need letter to stay a tab character, just be drawn differently.